# CSS: Hide a portion of shadow

Tags: css

I have a CSS menu in my page. When I hover the mouse over the items, their drop-down menu appears. I've used some css shadows like this:

```
#menu li:hover
{
    //...
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 0px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0px 5px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

also in my drop-down class, I've used some shadows:

```
.drop-down
{
    //...
    display:none;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px #000;
}
```

the result looks like this:

[image: Shadow]

So my question is, how can I hide the shadow under *First Item* and make the drop-down and menu look like one single object (not separated)?

**EDIT**:
here's the html and the css to show the drop-down:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">First Item</a>
    <div class="drop-down">
        <div>
            ...</div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>

#menu li:hover .drop-down
{
    left: -1px;
    display: block;
    top: auto;
}
```

here is a [simple version of that in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zDtXS/5/)

Comment: It is difficult to tell without your html, but you will have to remove the bottom shadow from `#menu li:hover` and top shadow from `.drop-down`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the HTML and a little more css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want a single border to apply around both the menu item text and the revealed menu. The main problem with this in the jsfiddle you posted seems to be that `.drop-down` has an absolute position so is not inside its parent's div block. Of course, you want the drop-down menus to be absolutely positioned so they don't affect the other elements on the page (i.e. pushing down the body text).

Therefore, the best solution might be to **repeat** the menu text inside the drop-down, and absolutely position it up one line so it covers the original menu text. That way, you can apply whatever styling you want to it as a unit.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do that? I've never created such complex shape.

Comment: You can do this using `potition: absolute` in the css. However, the most pragmatic solution may be to search online for a javascript menu that you like and use that - there are lots of free resources for this sort of thing.

Comment: I want to use a CSS menu and it's kind of done. The only problem is the shadow and if it produces much problem, I prefer removing the shadow over using another menu. Thanks for the help.